# foreach loop in tikz and math mode

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

Here is what I want to do:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 

\foreach \i in {1,...,8}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,8}
        \foreach \t in {1,2,3}{
            \node () at (\i,\t,\j) {$X_{\i,\j,\t}$};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I want to create a set of nodes in 3D, with certain math labels.
Unfortunately, Tikz does not allow me to do a naive thing like this, any help is appreciated!

**Update**
Okay-- This is a dumb question. It seems like Tikz is interfered by some other packages and making errors, I removed a bunch of packages and it works...

Comment: `\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 

\foreach \i in {1,...,8}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,8}
        \foreach \t in {1,2,3}{
            \node () at (\i,\t,\j) {$X_{\i,\j,\t}$};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}` works. What problems do you encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a minimal compilable example, and you need to describe your problem. What do you mean by TikZ does not allow you to do it?

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\foreach \i in {1,...,8}
    \foreach \j in {1,...,8}
        \foreach \t in {1,2,3}{
            \node () at (\i,\t,\j) {$X_{\i,\j,\t}$};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Nodes in 3D]

Comment: I think the problem was caused by other packages, I removed a lot of packages and error disappeared. Thanks!